# How do I open a popup window that contains a form

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I have a form and I want if user submit that form then the action page will open in pop up

Comment: To the people voting to close this question: Yes, it's worded poorly, but isn't it obvious what he's asking? Better to propose clarifying edits than to close it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function openwindow (url) {
   var win = window.open(url, "window1", "width=600,height=400,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes");
   win.focus();
}
</script>

<button value="send" onclick="openwindow('http://google.com')" />
```

or you use the target-attribute, like the other said. the target-solution is the better choice if you want to pass data of form-elements to your action page

keep in mind that popup-blockers may block this action

Answer (score 8):

Use the `target` attribute of the `form` tag:

```
<form action="#" target="_blank"></form>
```

See: [form](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_form_target.asp).